# Set Music Playback Slider in Music Player App with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, uislider, audio-player

music app contain track slider to control the music playback ,this is the code i used in objective-c to set the value of the slider

```
TrackSlider.maximumValue = Player.duration;
TrackSlider.minimumValue = 0;
Player.currentTime = TrackSlider.value;
```

now in swift and the new xCode this code is no more working i got this error

```
'NSTimeInterval' is not convertible to 'Float'
'Float' is not convertible to 'NSTimeInterval'
```

is there a way to convert the slider value(float) to the player.currentTime(NSTimeInterval) or the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider this example:

```
var interval: NSTimeInterval = 12.48
let myFloat: Float32 = 12.67
interval = myFloat //Compile time error: 'Float32' is not convertible to 'NSTimeInterval'
interval = Double(myFloat) // works as NSTimeInterval is a typealias for Double
```

If your case is similar to this example, you need to cast your `TrackSlider.value`.

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to know and the same can be done with setting the slider float value `TrackSlider.value = Float(Player.currentTime)` , if i had this problem in obj-c i used to do this `TrackSlider.value =(Float)Player.currentTime;` , that new Approach in swift is easier but not expected :D , thanks :)